# Can I combine the results from multiple columns into a single column without UNION? in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to combine 2 column output into one column.

Example :

```
select 1 as id, 2 as exid
```

**Current** output:

```
id | exid 
1  |    2
```

but I want output like the following :

```
id
 1
 2
```

If I use `Concat` function then output looks like this :

```
id  
12
```

and I don't want to this type of output.

**Note** : I don't want to use `UNION` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Unpivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) will help you to achieve what you are trying to do

```
select exprid [id] from
(select 1 [id],2 [expid]
) s
unpivot (exprid for col in (id,expid)) as t2
```

Compared to the using union this should be faster because it will only scan the table once instead of twice.

Answer (score 0):

Another method uses `outer apply`:

```
select x.*
from t outer apply
     (values (id), (exid)) x(id);
```

However, `union all` is a very reasonable approach, so I would often recommend using that.

Comment: Yes I know "union all" is  good approach...but it decrease the performance.

Comment: @Nirali . . . It scans the table twice.  Assuming the table fits in memory,then the performance should be fine.  There are some cases where optimizing such performance is important, but you would have to have a very large table for this to make a difference.

Comment: @Gordon...thank you so much....It is just example...I have used large table and I have also used store procedure in query.....I am beginner in SQL... I just know "UNION ALL" is decreased the performance.....so I am not sure if I will used "UNION ALL"  then It will decrease performance or not...so It is ok with performance if I will used "UNION ALL"?...for this question thanks in advance..:)